# Using the same code base for aks and service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-aks

Currently I am working on a project to provide Restful APIs on Azure. We want to deploy the project to both Azure Kubernetes and Service Fabric. Is there any possibility to do that? And how to implement the CI/CD on Azure?

We need to maintain all code login in a single project. Then create a deployment package for both aks and service fabric using the different configuration files/scripts. Or, we may have 2 extra projects in the same solution, 1 for aks, 1 for service fabric.

Those 2 options are all acceptable. Is there any sample or guide?

Answer (score 0):

both aks and service fabric supports microservices deployment orchestration, if you would elaborate where are you facing the challenge, I or someone will be able to help you out in a more better way.

Azure has devops resources, so you can create CICD even easily. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/product-categories/devops/

If you want to create your own CICD structure, there are tools like Jenkins. travis CI, terraform, ansible, chef, etc. that you can start looking in.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abhi, I have updated my post. Please see the info is enough for you to help me or not.